# IOS: Timing issue with hiding images on screen using performSelector

Tags: ios

In my `ViewController`, I attempt to hide two images (currently displayed) at the same time, but after a delay of 3 seconds. I usr

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideThem:) withObject:val afterDelay:3.0];
```

where "`hideThem`" is a routine that uses the following to hide the images. "val" is simply a `NSNumber`, not important to this question.

```
  [image1 setHidden:YES];  
  [image2 setHidden:YES];
```

If I call "`hideThem`" directly (not using `performSelector`), both images disappear at the exact same time, which is the desired affect.

If, I use the `performSelector`, as shown, one image will hide, then after 0.5 seconds (or so) and the other image will hide. I do not have my own run loop. The images are `UIImageView` objects and are part of the view hierarchy under "self".

I assume this is an effect with how `IOS` handles timing of events, but I don't understand why the effect of the `setHidden` will occur with that 0.5 second delay when both should be set up as hidden "after" the `performSelector` call to "`hideThem`" fires.

What about IOS causes this behavior?

What are the recommended approaches to resolve this issue (so that, after 3 seconds, both images are hidden, visually, at the same time.

Comment: When you send the performSelector you do this on the main thread? What I suggest you do is add a 'assert([NSThread isMainThread]);' to your method, also add 3 log messages at top, middle, and bottom of the setHidden and see if there is a time difference. Update the question if you find anything. Also, since hidden is a property, you can do image1.hidden = YES; (if you want - less typing).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Answers are: "hideThem" is in the main thread. The log message appear at what seems to be the same time. And yes, that would save typing :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why such an issue would occur but I can give you an alternative using GCD:

```
double delayInSeconds = 3.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self hideThem];
});
```

Comment: I tried this suggestions (thanks). It produced exactly the same results (still the approximately 0.5 seconds between image hiding). There must be something about how IOS is processing when "hiding" takes place in the view hierarchy. Note there are approximately 30 images in the hierarchy that are currently being displayed. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: NOTE: I have found something interesting. It seems that one image disappears after a few seconds, but prior to the hideThem getting called (based on the log messages). Of course, when log messages show up might have inherent delays. However, this may imply another code path having influence. I will investigate this possibility and report back.

Comment: Follow-up:  Indeed, using breakpoint instead of logs, it is definitely the case that one image is gone BEFORE hideThem is executed (but after the performSelector is invoked). After some searching I have yet to find out why (even put logs in the related UIImageView dealloc to see it if was removed somehow). So, still searching.

Answer (score 0):

1)
I can see a colon `:` in method call `@selector(hideThem:)`, double check whether your hideThem method takes input parameters.

2)
Make sure you call this `[self performSelector:@selector(hideThem:) withObject:val afterDelay:3.0];`
on main thread

try,

```
performSelectorOnMainThread
```

Comment: 1) Yes, "hideThem" gets one input parameter.   2) I am not sure how to call performSelectorOnMainThread with a delay of 3 seconds. However, as I indicated in an above comment, "hideThem" is executed on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas [I thought of 2 first but I suspect 1 will do the trick]:

1) Instead of setting their hidden property, use the UIView animation to turn both of their alphas to 0 over say a 100ms period, and in the completion block, set their hidden property to YES and reset their alphas back to 1.

2) Instead of hiding the two views immediately, create a new view to overlay them. You could even take a "snapshot" of what is under them and create an image out of that first:

- create an image that you can use temporarily to overlay the two images you want to hide.
- at the appropriate time, add that view to the hierarchy as the topmost view.
- hide the two views under it
- remove the temporary view

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. Thanks for all the suggestions which helped me to isolate the issue. And, David H... very interesting ideas and I may actually have use for them as the project continues.

The answer is:  after lots of searching, commenting out code, and tracking through things with logs I finally found ANOTHER related performSelector that was getting called elsewhere, with a timeframe of 2 seconds (hence, what I thought was showing a .5 sec delta between image hidings ).

In short...  a strange coding bug.
Thanks again!